# Find a $\delta$ shuch that $0<|x-1|<\delta\Rightarrow|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon\;\;\;\;$ $\;\forall\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

The way in which I solved it doesn´t lead to the same answer as the answer book so I wanted to know if it´s a valid answer.

---

**Problem:**

Find a $\delta$ shuch that $0<|x-1|<\delta\Rightarrow|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon\;\;\;\;$ $\;\forall\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

**My solution:**

$$|\sqrt x-1|<\sqrt x+1$$
thus
$$\sqrt x+1<\epsilon\Rightarrow|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon$$
$$|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1\Rightarrow |\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{(1).}$$
If $|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$ is true, then $|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon$ is true, we just have to find a $\delta$ such that, $\forall x$, $|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$.

We also have
$$\delta>|x-1|\geq|x|-1$$
thus
$$|x|-1<\delta$$
$$|x|<\delta+1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{(2)}$$
therefore, in order for $|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$ to be true$\;\forall x$, by (1) and (2), we must have a $\delta$ such that
$$|x|<\delta+1<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$$
so
$$\delta<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon$$
but $\epsilon^2-2\epsilon<0\;\forall\epsilon\in(0,1)$ which leads to
$$\delta<0$$
but $\delta>0$, a contradiction.

Where did I go wrong?

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $|\sqrt{x}-1|=\frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{x}+1}$. Now you need to bound $\sqrt{x}+1$.

Comment: (1) is not true; for example x = 1/5 and epsilon =1/2.

Comment: @NoName , what (1) is saying is that if $|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$ where to be true, then $|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon$ would be true. We then (in (2)) proceed to search for which $x\;$ $\;|x|<\epsilon^2-2\epsilon+1$ is ture and thats how we pick $\delta$, our restriction on $x$.

Comment: @Sebastijo At the very start when you've $\sqrt x+1<\epsilon$ you're already assuming that, at least, $\epsilon > 1+0 = 1$ when what your epsilon is supposed to be in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @NoName , Thak you so much, now I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before (1), $\sqrt x+1<\epsilon\Rightarrow|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon\;$ is stated. But $\sqrt x+1<\epsilon$ can not be true for any $x$ because the smalest value for epsilon would be at $x=0$ which gives
$$1<\epsilon$$
which, of course can´t be true since $\epsilon\in(0,1).$

---

Thanks to @NoName for pointing this out.